# flipping div using jquery after 5 secs

Tags: jquery, timer, flip

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M783F/5/

```
<div class="stage">
  <div class="flashcard">
    <div class="front">
     <p>Front</p>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
   <p>Back</p>
  </div>
 </div>  
 </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.flashcard').on('click', function() {
  $('.flashcard').toggleClass('flipped');
});
});
```

by the above code, currently the front and back div is flipped when someone clicks on the div.

i want that the front and back div should be flipped automatically after some time (say 5 secs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JS Fiddle is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/asomani/kr4s4k7f/4/)
    Use set Interval.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flashcard').on('click', function() {
    $('.flashcard').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) function. It calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay (milliseconds).

```
setTimeout(function(){$('.flashcard').toggleClass('flipped');}, 5000);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M783F/24/)

Comment: Why is your code for 3 seconds instead of 5 seconds?

Comment: It is just an example. OP can set any value. Anyway I'll update it.

Comment: I understand that, but at the very least you should follow the question and explain what is happening. Maybe he has no idea that number is in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I understood. Added a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Use [setInterval](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setInterval.html). It will flip the div after each 5 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.flashcard').toggleClass('flipped');
  },5000);
});
```

If you want to flip just once use [setTimeout](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html).

Answer (score 0):

`SetTimeOut` to execute method one time and `setInterval` to loop it every `n` secounds

```
setInterval(function(){$('.flashcard').toggleClass('flipped')},5000);
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M783F/21/)

Comment: You can vote up and accept the answer, if it solved your purpose. Thanks in advance